# pytorch - modify embedding backpropagation

Tags: pytorch, word-embedding

I would like to modify the back-propagation for the embedding layer but I don't understand where the definition is.

In the definition available in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html in the embedding function, they call `torch.embedding` and here there should be defined how the weights are updated.

**So my question is:**
Where can I find the documentation of `torch.embedding`?

Answer (score 0):

It calls underlying C function, in my torch build(version 4) [this file](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Embedding.cpp).